# Play 2.0 forkjoin thread count high

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

I'm currently evaluating play 2.0 framework in async scenario. I did an experiment as below:

```
def test = Action {
  val futureResponse: Future[play.libs.WS.Response] = scala.concurrent.Future {
    val remoteCall = WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/slowweb/SlowServlet1").get();
    remoteCall.get(); 
  }
  Async {
    futureResponse.map(response => Ok("Got result: " + response.getBody()))
  }
}
```

The ":8080/slowweb/SlowServlet1" is a simulation of a slow web service call, it takes 2s to return.

Then I run jmeter against the endpoint ":9000/test". I observed the following behaviour: If I run 50 threads in jmeter, the forkjoin pool size is 50; if I run 200 threads in jmeter, the forkjoin pool size is 200.

It looks to me the thread pool size is the same as the concurrent request size. What I expect is the thread pool size should be much smaller if using async approach.

Have I done something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is related to your error, but your code could be simplified to this:

```
def test = Action {
   Async {
     val futureResponse: Future[play.libs.WS.Response] = 
        WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/slowweb/SlowServlet1").get();

     futureResponse.map(response => Ok("Got result: " + response.getBody()))
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But "WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/slowweb/SlowServlet1").get();" returns F.Promise[Response], instead of a Future.

Comment: Hi Ekito, Looks like the problem resolved. I take your suggestion and changed the line to: val futureResponse: Future[play.libs.WS.Response] = WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/slowweb/SlowServlet1").get().getWrappedPromise();